# gsutil notification watchbucket returns "BadRequestException: 400 No valid domain for WebHook callback: https://https://..."

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Following the instructions in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorize_Endpoint I'm trying to set a watchbucket notification.
I'm running:

```
gsutil notification watchbucket https://-------.appspot.com  gs://-----
```

(with my real application id and bucket)
The error string reported by gsutil suggest an internal bug:

```
BadRequestException: 400 No valid domain for WebHook callback: https://https://...
```

**Note the double https://** in the error report

trying to remove the https:// ends with an error:

```
CommandException: The application URL must be an https:// URL.
```

I believe I've done all the things needed. I'm working with a service account of the application. the application URL is listed in https://console.developers.google.com/project/ywz-gcs-watch/apiui/notification. The service account has access to the watch bucket (tried it also with a bucket belong to the application project)

Is that a gsutil bug?

Answer (score 4):

I've faced the exactly same problem here. The issue was that my allowed domain was registered like 'https://example.com' while it should be 'example.com'.

Go to your google developer console and open your project page.
In the sidebar on the left, click APIs & auth, then click Push.
Double check if your domain is correct. If not, enter just the domain without the protocol part and wait a few minutes before test again. Hope it helps!

Kindly Regards,
Vinícius Miasato

Comment: Thanks. That's odd, as the documentation https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Authorize_Endpoint specifically say it should starts with https. My problem is that I'm using google app engine for which I cannot do domain verification (domain verification is just for top level domains not subdomains and the top level is not mine). but it could be that is exactly my problem

Comment: Make sure that you have your ```https://example.com``` deleted and that ```example.com``` is added, huge key part.